# How Sub Level displays its bands without inhiriting it from the parent Main View at DevExpress Grid Control

Tags: gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm using DevExpress 10.2 For WinForms with .Net Framework 4.0
I have a form that contains grid having bands and this grid has Main View and Level inside it
so it sounds like a banded  grid inside another banded  grid.
as shown below:
[image: Main View At Design time]
the major problem that the sub grid at level 1 contains also bands as seen at the following screenshot:
[image: Sub Level View At Design Time]

but at run-time it retrieves the bands of the parent view instead of its bands
as shown below:
[image]

** please note that the data source given to the gridControl is a dataset which has two datatable inside it connected each other using **DataRelation** Class

Answer (score 0):

it solved by adding the following code

```
this.dgGeneralLedger.LevelTree.Nodes[0].RelationName = "Transaction";
                    this.dgGeneralLedger.ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails = true;
                    this.dgGeneralLedger.DataSource = result.DatSet.Tables["LedgerAccounts"];
```